# Reliable path for add-on data storage

Tags: python, add-on

How can I use the python API to find the most reliable location that an add-on can use to store data like images, assets, etc. automatically?

It's important that this location:

- doesn't change for different versions of blender
- doesn't get deleted on system reboot like some temp folders
- is available on every OS

One option I've found is to use `bpy.utils.resource_path('USER')` which ends in the version number (on windows `C:\Users\blah\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78`), but then do a [relative jump](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9856725/2488994) to the folder above it. Is there a better way?

Comment: Wrote an answer, but then realized it's not automatic as the user has to set a folder in the addon prefs.  This is a one time thing if the user enables addon and saves user prefs.

Comment: Maybe we should add a new key 'DATA' to that function? I've already made a suggestion for [CACHE](https://developer.blender.org/T47684). I might get around to implementing it some day ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**Set it once in the addons User Preferences.**

Suggest using a property in  [addon preferences](https://www.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AddonPreferences.html)  The user chooses the folder.  I had deleted this answer, as it is not "automatic", however setting a storage location once,  is IMO, not a huge overhead.

Modify the script in link with a folder property

```
class ExampleAddonPreferences(AddonPreferences):
    # this must match the addon name, use '__package__'
    # when defining this in a submodule of a python package.
    bl_idname = __name__

    assets_folder = StringProperty(
            name="Assets Folder",
            subtype='DIR_PATH',
            )

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="This is a preferences view for our addon")
        layout.prop(self, "assets_folder")
```

[image]

And then when you need to access it

```
    preferences = context.preferences
    addon_prefs = preferences.addons[__name__].preferences

    assets_folder = addon_prefs.assets_folder
```

Answer (score 2):

What about `os.path.expanduser('~')`?

From what i read on https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html it should work for all UNIX system and Windows. Moreover it is assured that the user have write permission in it.

Comment: That does seem like quite a good solution, the only slight disadvantage being it's not in a blender-specific location. For reference, on windows this resolves to `C:\Users\you`, on linux I assume it's just the home directory.