# script addon Blender filepath

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I wrote a little script addon but I can't put operator in panel with filepath to export to folder. The example under, I wan't to replace path with panel.

```
# EXPORTE EN COLLADA -
class ColladaExport(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.colladaexport"
    bl_label = "Collada export"

    def execute(self, context):
        path = "D:\Documents\VR\mixedRea\polypheme\models"
        selection = bpy.context.selected_editable_objects
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        for obj in selection:
            if obj.type == 'MESH':
                obj.select = True
                bpy.ops.wm.collada_export(filepath = path + "/" + obj.name,
                                          check_existing = False,
                                          filter_blender = False,
                                          filter_image = False,
                                          filter_movie = False,
                                          filter_python = False,
                                          filter_font = False,
                                          filter_sound = False,
                                          filter_text = False,
                                          filter_btx = False,
                                          filter_collada = True,
                                          filter_folder = True,
                                          filemode = 8,
                                          selected = True,
                                          active_uv_only = True)
                obj.select = False

        for obj in selection:
            obj.select = True
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Thank you
Thank you very much for these indications. I'm going fast with an ant ... I followed your directions. The good text is written correctly with the brother button But the recording in collada in the chosen file does not work. Here is the script:

```
import bpy
import os

from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty, EnumProperty
from bpy.types import Operator

class ColladaExport(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.colladaexport"
    bl_label = "Export collada"
    filter_folder = BoolProperty(default=True) # only folders
    directory = StringProperty(subtype='DIR_PATH')

    def execute(self, context):
        selection = [o for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH']
        scene = context.scene
        for ob in context.selected_objects:
            ob.select = False

        for obj in selection:

            scene.objects.active = obj
            obj.select = True
            filepath = os.path.join(self.directory, "%s.dae" % obj.name)

            bpy.ops.wm.collada_export(filepath=filepath, check_existing=False, filter_blender=False, filter_image=False, filter_movie=False, filter_python=False, filter_font=False, filter_sound=False, filter_text=False, filter_btx=False, filter_collada=True, filter_folder=True, filemode=8, selected=True, active_uv_only=True)

            print("collada export", filepath)
            obj.select = False

        for obj in selection:
            obj.select = True
        return {'FINISHED'}


class VrTools(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_category = "Tools"
    bl_context = "objectmode"
    bl_label = "VR Tools"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        self.layout.prop(context.scene, "directory")
        op = self.layout.operator("object.colladaexport")
        op.directory = context.scene.directory

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ColladaExport)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VrTools)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ColladaExport)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VrTools)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: You need to create a StringProperty to hold your path, then to access it in panel with `layout.prop(...)`.

Comment: Don't use backslashes for file paths, or escape them properly. Use either `r"D:\Documents\VR\mixedRea\polypheme\models"`, `"D:\\Documents\\VR\mixedRea\\polypheme\\models"`, or `"D:/Documents/VR\mixedRea/polypheme/models"`

Answer (score 2):

**Invoke the filebrowser**

If the filebrowser is invoked with only a `directory` property and no `filepath` it will only have choice of folder to export to.  Possibly more handy than having a path to set in the UI.

To call the operator from code with a directory use `bpy.ops.object.colladaexport(directory="/tmp")` and it wont invoke the filebrowser.

```
import bpy
import os

from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty, EnumProperty
from bpy.types import Operator

class ColladaExport(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.colladaexport"
    bl_label = "Multi Collada export"
    filter_folder = BoolProperty(default=True) # only folders
    directory = StringProperty(subtype='DIR_PATH')

    def execute(self, context):

        selection = [o for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH']
        scene = context.scene
        for ob in context.selected_objects:
            ob.select = False

        for obj in selection:
            scene.objects.active = obj
            obj.select = True
            filepath = os.path.join(self.directory, "%s.dae" % obj.name)
            '''
            bpy.ops.export_scene.collada(
                    filepath=filepath,
                    use_selection=True,
                    )
            '''
            print("collada export", filepath)
            obj.select = False

        for obj in selection:
            obj.select = True
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.fileselect_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

# Only needed if you want to add into a dynamic menu
def menu_func_export(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ColladaExport.bl_idname, text="Text Export Operator")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ColladaExport)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(menu_func_export)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ColladaExport)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func_export)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.colladaexport('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Note: just found out the collada exporter I have doesn't work, so I commented it out

**As a stand alone property**

If you wish to define a directory on say the scene object, use the `'DIR_PATH'` sub-type of a `StringProperty`

```
bpy.types.Scene.directory = StringProperty(subtype='DIR_PATH`)
```

can display in a draw method via

```
self.layout.prop(context.scene, "directory")
```

which will include a browse button in layout to set folder using filebrowser, like that shown for setting the render output folder.

[image]

and can use this setting in operator above from draw method with

```
op = self.layout.operator("object.colladaexport")
op.directory = context.scene.directory
```

in which case could remove the `invoke` method in operator above to not invoke the file browser.

Since you are using if for an addon, saving to the addons user preferences would be a good option.  [See this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/70587/15543)

**EDIT**  given the edit to your question, you need to register the scene property.

```
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ColladaExport)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VrTools)
    bpy.types.Scene.directory = StringProperty(subtype='DIR_PATH')


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ColladaExport)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VrTools)
    del(bpy.types.Scene.directory)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood a number of things thanks to you. But in fact I did not speak well (my English is not good). To be honest, this is an addon to help put 3D models in VR with A-Frame. Here is the whole code of my addon. I wish I could enter the destination folder of my selection in a text box and I sadly fails on this detail. Thank you so much.

Comment: You forgot to paste the link?

Comment: 320/5000
Thanks thanks. I did everything right. it's very nice, but it does not save the collada file in the destination folder I chose. I think it's the "filepath" that is not recognized .. I give up. I will manually enter the destination file each time. Thank you for this valuable information. See my sad failure on the blend file:                                             https://www.olborne.com/telechargement/exportCollada.blend